# using HtmlAgilityPack for parsing a web page information in C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use HtmlAgilityPack for parsing a web page information. This is my code:

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace htmparsing
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://bugs.eclipse.org";
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
            foreach(HtmlNode node in doc){
                //do something here with "node"
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried to access to `doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes` I can not see `DocumentElement` in the list. I added the HtmlAgilityPack.dll in the references, but I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: `doc1.DocumentElement` or `doc1.DocumentNode` ? (BTW is it `doc` or `doc1` ?)

Comment: I don't know, right now it shows me DocumentNode, but in some tutorial I found DocumentElement. so it seems DocumentNode is the correct one

Comment: `but in some tutorial I found DocumentElement.` For example?

Comment: can you check this link please http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Comment: can you introduce a tutorial for htmlagilitypack? I'm a beginner

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've an article that demonstrates scraping DOM elements with HAP (HTML Agility Pack) using ASP.NET. It simply lets you go through the whole process step by step. You can have a look and try it.

[**Scraping HTML DOM elements using HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) in ASP.NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H)

and about your process it's working fine for me. I've tried this way as you did with a single change.

```
string url = "https://www.google.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")) 
{
    outputLabel.Text += node.InnerHtml;
}
```

Got the output as expected. The problem is you are asking for **DocumentElement** from **HtmlDocument** object which actually should be **DocumentNode**. Here's a response from a developer of **HTMLAgilityPack** about the problem you are facing.

[**HTMLDocument.DocumentElement not in object browser**](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/250435)

Comment: how would you foreach thru every element on the page, not just a tags?

Answer (score 1):

### The behavior you are seeing is correct.

Look at what you're actually doing: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs .

You're asking the top element to select nodes matching some xpath.  Unless your xpath expression starts with a `//`, you're asking it for relative nodes, which are descendant nodes.  A document element is a not a descendant of itself, because no element is a descendant of itself.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, leave a comment.  This answer is correct and the vote is misleading