# How to create Regexp for html page

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have html page with this code

```
<table class="data">
        <tr>
            <td class="head" >Time</td>
            <td class="head right" >Pref</td>
            <td class="head" >Name</td>
            <td class="head">Descr</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="date">
                2014.03.17
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" class="dat">
                    <td>22:02</td>
                    <td class="right">
                    3/2014
                     </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/reports/id=34">
                    <b>Company Name</b>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href=/reports/view/id=34" target="_blank" class="th">
                    Description 
                        </a>
                    </td>

        </tr>

        <tr valign="top" class="date">

                    <td>21:16</td>
                    <td class="right">
                        8/2014
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/reports/id=324">
                            <b>Company Name2</b>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="reports/view/=324" target="_blank" class="th">
                        Description
                        </a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
................................
</table>
```

Can you help me create regexp to extract data from table. I need this data 21:16,8/2014,Company Name2,Description

Thanks.

Comment: You will be better off using a parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/794380

Comment: @IdanArye I just posted that :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you researched today? This is too general.

Comment: @BlueIce 3 seconds before me...

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regexp is the road to eternal damnation. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1864610)

Comment: @MikeW Nice! 3 links to the same question!

Comment: @BlueIce 3 comments and an answer now. I hope the OP gets the message

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT try parsing HTML with Regex. You might get fairly far, but it's very easy to screw it up and it doesn't work well. It learned this the hard way once. Like others have mentioned in the comments. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/794380

Answer (score 1):

You should try the Html Agility pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871589/307976