# Is there a software to read local .hist files saved by Lync?

Tags: file, lync

I'm using Lynch at my work place. But none of us was able to save the convo history in outlook as expected.
Basically when I close the conversation window, all history is lost.

After some search, I found that the convo history is actually stored in local files under:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\sip_user@domain\History Spooler
```

and there's a bunch of files with .hist extension, containing a "weird" header and the conversation  in HTML format.

Is there any software to read/access those files in a "clean" way?

That said, I found Lync SDK but it's to be used server side.
I don't have access to the server, nor any network resources. Just local .hist files.

Till now, I was able to open those files in a browser, by renaming them to .html(with some garbage at top of page due to the "weird" header).

Next step was to write some code, in order to parse those files, as asked here: [How can I read a Lync conversation file containing HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649545/how-can-i-read-a-lync-conversation-file-containing-html)
but not much came out of it.

Comment: I know you were adviced to ask a new question but this has now become a tool recommendation and that is off-topic on SO. Due to the special character I doubt it is on-topic on [Software Recommendation](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) but you could check on their meta first.

Answer (score 1):

This is temporary solution to view lync history under you mentioned path
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\sip_user@domain\History Spooler.

You need to change .hist to .HTML format. After double click the .html file. Now you are able to see the proper chat data.